# Does AWS API gateway calls takes long if executed multiple times in 1 second?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

API Gateway is connected to a lambda function that sleeps for 4 seconds. When I execute the API 20 times in 1 second, the first few calls completes the job in 5 seconds but the other calls take more time eg:12 sec,20 sec, and sometimes runs into timeout errors

1. Are the APIs dependent on its previous calls (i.e) for the 20th API call to get executed the other previous calls must be completed?
2. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider when working with AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda.

Creating an instance (execution environment) of your Lambda Function takes a while. This is called a cold start. If your Lambda runs in a VPC this might take longer. Shouldn't take less than a couple seconds though.

Once that Lamdba runs, API Gateway can reuse this instance. If there isn't traffic for some time the Lamdba goes back to cold storage. The next request through API Gateway will create another instance of the Lambda.

Given enough traffic AWS Lambda triggers concurrent executions, which means there will be more Lambda instances. This is called automatic scaling. Again, it takes a cold start. You have no control when, or how many Lambda instances are running. Welcome to serverless.

AWS Lambda limits its execution time to 15 minutes. Your function cannot exceed this limit. It will be shutdown hard.

API Gateway has an integration timeout of 30 seconds. This means your Lambda needs to finish within **30 seconds**. Otherwise API Gateway returns 502 while your function is still running.

Comment: Thanks, Raupach. How to resolve this problem? My lambda function is connected to EFS to get the packages. I made a sample code that sleeps for 5 seconds. When I execute the API multiple times with connection to EFS, the API throws a timeout error after the 5th call but without the connection, the sleep code works smoothly even if I call 30 times. I can't upload the python packages directly to Lambda as the limit of lambda is 250MB whereas the size of my package is over 500MB. EFS is causing latency issues. So How to get the python packages so that the lambda works smoothly? Any alternatives?

Comment: Why don't you try Lambda Layers? Eliminates the call to EFS to download packages.

Comment: Isn't the lambda layer part of the deployment package? So again the 250MB limit right. "The total unzipped size of the function and all layers can't exceed the unzipped deployment package size limit of 250 MB" -- AWS website (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)